# Customizing Autodesk GuiViewer3D toolbar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Autodesk viewer v7

```
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js'
script.async = true
script.onload = () => setDeskLoaded(true)
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

I am following the documentation on creating an extension to modify the toolbar, but it is failing to detect .onToolbarCreated, I need to add some buttons to the existing toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not receive the event, this is certainly because your extension is loaded at a time the toolbars are already created. This event is thrown only when the viewer creates its toolbar. The sample you've seen is probably assuming you are loading the extension at initialisation time.

In your code, you have to check the viewer state to decide if you need to create an event handler or go straight to your toolbar code. I usually do the following:

```js
if ( this.viewer.getToolbar(true) )
  this.onToolbarCreated();
else
  this.viewer.addEventListener(
    Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT,
    this.onToolbarCreated.bind(this)
  );
```